# How can I show that the characters in sense of irreducible representations are the same as the character maps from the burnside matrices?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

My Task is:
Let G be a finite group. 1. Let $C_1 = \{e\}, C_2,..., C_k$ be the conjugacy classes, and let $v_1,..., v_k$ be the normalised eigenvectors of the Burnside matrices of G, then for all s $\in \{1,..., k\}$ we defined the maps $\chi_s:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C},g\mapsto \sqrt{|G|}\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{v_{sj}}{\sqrt{|C_j|}}\delta_{C_j}(g)$
2. And For any representation $\rho$ of G we defined the map $ch(\rho):x \mapsto Tr(\rho)$

We want to show that the characters in the sense of 2. of irreducible representations are exactly the characters in the sense of 1.
For all s $\in\{1,..., k\}$ let
$V_s := Span\{x\mapsto \chi_s(xy^{-1})| y \in G\}$
Recall that $V_s$ is an invariant subspace for all linear transformations L(g), g $\in$ G.
Assume that for every  s $\in\{1,..., k\}$ there is an invariant subspace W $\subseteq V_s$ w.r.t. $L^{V_s}$ such that the restriction $L^W=L^{V_s}|_W \in GL(W)$ of the linear operator $L^{V_s}$ from $V_s$ to W defines an irreducible, unitary representation G on the subspace W. Show that then $ch(L^W)=\chi_s$,and conclude that the characters in the sense of 2. ao irreducible representations are exactly the characters in the sense of 1.
(Hint: Observe that every class function in W $\subset V_s$ is a multiple of $\chi_s(g)$,  $( \chi_s, \chi_s)_G=1$, $\chi_s(e)=\sqrt{|G|} v_{s1} > 0$, $(ch(L^W),ch(L^W))_G=1$ and  $ch(L^W)(e)=dim(W) >0$.)

I've been working on that execise with others for some weeks now but we can't solve it.

What we have till now is:
(1) ch($\rho$) is a class function
(2) every class function in $V_s$ is a multiple of $\chi_s$
(3) $( \chi_s, \chi_s)_G=1$
(4) $(ch(L^W),ch(L^W))_G=1$
(5) $\chi_s(e)=\sqrt{|G|} v_{s1} > 0$
(6) $ch(L^W)(e)=dim(W) >0$

proof: "$\Rightarrow$"
$  
W \subset V_s \overset{(2)}{\Rightarrow} every \ class \ function \ in \ W \ is \ a \ multiple \ of \ \chi_s $
$  
\overset{(1)}{\Rightarrow} ch(L^W) is \ a \ class \ function \ in \ W \Rightarrow ch(L^W)=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \chi_i$
$ch(L^W)=\chi_s \Leftrightarrow \alpha_i=\delta_{is} \Rightarrow $need to show that
and$  
\delta_{\alpha \beta}=(ch(L^{W_\alpha}),ch(L^{W_\beta})_G= \sum_{i=1}^k (\alpha_i \chi_i,\beta_i \chi_i)_G=(\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i) (\sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i)^*
$
$
(\Rightarrow \alpha_i =  <ch(L^W),\chi_i>)
$
$
\Rightarrow 1= \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_i \alpha_j^* \ and \ 0=\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_i \beta_j^*
$
now:$
ch(L^W)(e)=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \chi_i(e) \overset{(5),(6)}{\Leftrightarrow}$
$
dim(W)=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \sqrt{|G|} v_{i1}=\sqrt{|G|} \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i  v_{i1}
$

Answer (score 0):

Why is $ch(L^{W}) \in V_s$? This is not trivial. First prove:

$(\chi_{sy}, \chi_{sx})_G = \frac{1}{v_{s1}\sqrt{|G|}} \chi_{sy}(x)$

and then go from there via $ch(L^{W})(g) = tr(L^{W}(g))= \dots$

then you are almost done.

Comment: And don't feel bad, this is not easy, it even took me a couple of days ;)
Does your group have anything good on exercise (14)